# How can set right-to-left align in devexpress gridcontrol component?

Tags: c#, devexpress

How i can set right-to-left align in devexpress gridcontrol component ? (without using wpf)

like this picture:

[image: GridControl]

Comment: [DevExpress - PropertyGridControl Properties](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraVerticalGridPropertyGridControlClassPropTopic) 
try set as a <your_component>.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes;

Comment: This property exists, but does not work

Comment: Show your code of initialization this component. What other property used ? > "property exists, but does not work" - we don't understand... please more detail 
/ see also [doc. of how use PropertyGridControl Class](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraVerticalGridPropertyGridControltopic)

Comment: i used gridControl1.RightToLeft = System.Windows.Forms.RightToLeft.Yes; but not worked ... i want change layout

Answer (score 2):

In release 15.1 DevExpress introduced Right-To-Left (RTL) support across the following controls:

- Charts
- Grid controls (Grid, Treelist, Pivot Grid, Vertical Grid and Property Grid)
- Data Editors and Controls (Range Control, Rating Control, etc.)
- Ribbon, Menus and related controls (BackstageView, AppMenu, еtс.)
- Layout Control and layout containers (TabControl, GroupControl, etc.)
- Navigation Controls (Navigation Bar, Tile Control, etc.)
- Application UI Controls (Docking, DocumentManager, etc.)

So, just set `GridControl.RightToLeft` property to `RightToLeft.Yes` and you will get the RTL layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ms trick:

make new component and in code view add the following lines:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid.Localization
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class MirroredDevExpressGrid
   Private _Mirrored As Boolean
   Const WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = &H400000

   Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
      Get
         Dim CP As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams = _
               MyBase.CreateParams
         If Mirrored Then
            CP.ExStyle = CP.ExStyle Or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
            MyBase.Refresh()
         End If
         Return CP
      End Get
   End Property

   <Description("Change to the right-to-left layout."), _
  DefaultValue(False), Localizable(True), _
  Category("Appearance"), Browsable(True)> _
   Public Property Mirrored() As Boolean
      Get
         Return _Mirrored
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
         If _Mirrored <> value Then
            _Mirrored = value
            MyBase.OnRightToLeftChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
         End If
      End Set
   End Property

   Private Sub InitializeComponent()
      Me.GridView1 = New DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView
      CType(Me.GridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
      CType(Me, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
      Me.SuspendLayout()
      Me.LookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle("Money Twins")
      Me.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = False
      Me.Mirrored = True
      '
      'GridView1
      '
      Me.GridView1.GridControl = Me
      Me.GridView1.Name = "GridView1"
      '
      'MirroredDevExpressGrid
      '
      Me.MainView = Me.GridView1
      Me.ViewCollection.AddRange(New DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView() {Me.GridView1})
         CType(Me.GridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
      CType(Me, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
      Me.ResumeLayout(False)

   End Sub


   Private Sub MirroredDevExpressGrid_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

      Invalidate()
   End Sub

End Class

and in designer class:

you can use ms trick:

make new component and in code view add the following lines:

Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports DevExpress.XtraGrid.Localization
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class MirroredDevExpressGrid
   Private _Mirrored As Boolean
   Const WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL = &H400000

   Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
      Get
         Dim CP As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams = _
               MyBase.CreateParams
         If Mirrored Then
            CP.ExStyle = CP.ExStyle Or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL
            MyBase.Refresh()
         End If
         Return CP
      End Get
   End Property

   <Description("Change to the right-to-left layout."), _
  DefaultValue(False), Localizable(True), _
  Category("Appearance"), Browsable(True)> _
   Public Property Mirrored() As Boolean
      Get
         Return _Mirrored
      End Get
      Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
         If _Mirrored <> value Then
            _Mirrored = value
            MyBase.OnRightToLeftChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
         End If
      End Set
   End Property

   Private Sub InitializeComponent()
      Me.GridView1 = New DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView
      CType(Me.GridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
      CType(Me, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
      Me.SuspendLayout()
      Me.LookAndFeel.SetSkinStyle("Money Twins")
      Me.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = False
      Me.Mirrored = True
      '
      'GridView1
      '
      Me.GridView1.GridControl = Me
      Me.GridView1.Name = "GridView1"
      '
      'MirroredDevExpressGrid
      '
      Me.MainView = Me.GridView1
      Me.ViewCollection.AddRange(New DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.BaseView() {Me.GridView1})
         CType(Me.GridView1, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
      CType(Me, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
      Me.ResumeLayout(False)

   End Sub


   Private Sub MirroredDevExpressGrid_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseMove

      Invalidate()
   End Sub

End Class

and in designer class:

Partial Class MirroredDevExpressGrid
   Inherits DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl

   <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
 Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
      MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
   End Sub
   Friend WithEvents GridView1 As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView

End Class
```